# Why is my PASCAL program not running?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
Program TypeofCreditCard; 
Var 
   AppliName: array[1..99] of String; 
   SSnum: array[1..99] of Integer; 
    GSal: array[1..99] of Integer; 
   TSalD: array[1..99] of Integer; 

  Name, CC : String; 
  Rep,Exp, GS,NS,Sum,TSD , YS,SSN,i, ,PofIncome : integer ; 
  YS, C_Amt: Real

Begin 
   Writeln ( 'Enter applicants who applied for a type of credit card'); 
   Readln (Rep,Exp,GS,YS,NS,Sum,TSD,SSN,CC,PofIncome) ; 

While ( Name <> ' Stop ' ) do 
   Begin 
   NS:= GS-TSD ; 
   Sum:= Exp + Rep ; 
   PofIncome:=(NS * 0.45); 
Begin 
If ( GS >4000) AND ( CC = 'Bronze Card' ) then 
   YS:= GS * 12 ; 
   C_Amt := YS * 0.25; 
   i:= i + 1; 
   AppliName [i]:= Name; 
   SSNum [i]:= SSN ; 
   GSal  [i]:= GS ; 
   TSalD [i]:= TSD ; 
End ; 
Begin 
If (GS >= 7500) AND  (CC= 'Gold Card') then 
   YS:= GS * 12 ; 
   C_Amt:= YS * 0.3; 
   i:= i + 1 ; 
   AppliName [i]:= Name; 
   SSnum [i]:=SSN; 
   GSal [i]:=GS; 
   TSalD [i]:=TSD; 
End; 
Begin 
If (GS>=10,000) AND ( CC = ' Platinum Card') then 
   YS := GS * 12; 
   C_Amt: = YS * 0.4; 
   i:= i + 1; 
   AppliName [i]:= Name; 
   SSNum [i]:= SSN; 
   GSal [i]:=GS; 
   TSalD [i]:= TSD; 

End if 
End if 
End if 
End While 
End.
```

I am using free IDE Pascal and it is saying that I have 2 errors. If there are anymore errors or you see anything strange please inform me. The error says : Fatal:Syntax Error, ";" expected but "identifier Writeln found - Source of error- Writeln ( 'Enter applicants who applied for a type of credit card');

Answer (score 3):

There's a `;` missing after `YS, C_Amt: Real`. Also after each `then` should be a `begin`and all `End if` and `End while` at the end should all be `End;`